# HTTP POST - Escaping % Sign

Tags: java, json, http-post

I'm sending a POST request with a json object via java, containing a string which contains the % sign.

This returns an error code 500.
i'm guessing the problem is with the server i'm sending the request to, but still, i need to find a way to include the % sign in my string.

i tried escaping the % using

```
.replace("%","\\%")
```

this just made the json library throw an illegal escape error, which wasn't a big surprise.

Comment: How are you building and sending JSON?

Comment: You can try `replace("%", "%25")` if server performs URL decoding of the POST body, but that's very strange behavior. You should contact developers of that server to settle that issue.

Comment: You 'guess'? do not have you a stacktrace?

Comment: i only guessing because i don't know what a normal server behavior should be as i'm a novice. of-course, stack trace gives me 500 error

Comment: vbezhenar - your solution worked!